# Is there a g++ compiler flag to check if code builds in both c++11 and C++03

Tags: c++11, g++, c++03

I have two applications that depend on an internal in house library. One application uses other external libraries that are not ABI compatible with c++11. For this application I must compile my internal library without c++11.

The other application has no external dependencies and I would like to use some c++11 features in it.

I will probably end up modifying the internal library that both these applications depend on. Is there a flag in g++ that will alert me if I am adding features to the internal library that exist in c++11 but not in c++03?

Comment: If you don't use such things as `std::list` in that library, your program (written in C++11) can freely use old library (written in C++03). This is right for `libstdc++`. If you use `libc++` C++11 and C++03 code will always be binary-compatible.

Comment: Oh, and Clang has a `Wc++98-compat` flag, which warns you if you use some feature from c++11. GCC has no such flag.